# how to fill missing values in table using sql for window function

Tags: sql, postgresql, google-bigquery, window-functions

| order_id | Products | Country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MB-123 | Bread | US |
| MB-123 | Milk |  |
| MB-1256 | Cheese | UK |
| MB-1256 | Tomato Sauce |  |
| MB-1256 | Milk |  |

The missing values in the above table needs to be filled with the same country names for the same order_id.

I tried with coalesce with window function but I am not able to fill the null value for each orderid. I want null values in country column to be filled by the country name for the same order_id.

I want the desired output as the table shown below :-

| order_id | Products | Country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MB-123 | Bread | US |
| MB-123 | Milk | US |
| MB-1256 | Cheese | UK |
| MB-1256 | Tomato Sauce | UK |
| MB-1256 | Milk | UK |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PostgreSQL, you can use the `MAX` window function, that allows you to get the non-null value for each "*order_id*" partition.

```
SELECT order_id, Products, MAX(Country) OVER(PARTITION BY order_id) AS Country 
FROM tab
```

If you need to update the existing table, you can compute the maximum value for each country, then apply a `JOIN operation inside the` UPDATE` statement:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT order_id, Products, MAX(Country) OVER(PARTITION BY order_id) AS Country 
    FROM tab
)
UPDATE tab 
SET Country = cte.Country
FROM cte
WHERE cte.order_id = tab.order_id AND cte.Products = tab.products
  AND tab.Country IS NULL
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cMyjhhNZsKZYteuQUBXigE/0).